# Android:nextFocusDown not working

Tags: android

i have two editTexts which I want when you filled up the username you can just press a button to go to the next editText. I'm doing it on the `content_main.xml` Here is my code.

### content_main.xml

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etFirstname"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Username"
/>


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etFirstname"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:hint="Password" />
```

The editText only makes another line for the first EditText. Thanks guys :D

Comment: give max length or max line to first edittext.

Comment: set `android:single_line="true"`

Comment: @Viren - Still adds another line. Not going to the next editText.

Comment: @Shaishav - Thanks man! This does the trick. :)

Answer (score 3):

imeOptions `actionNext` should always used with `android:singleLine="true"` so add singleLine true to your xml.

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: singleLine is deprecated, use maxLine="1", but doen't work

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to add inputType and it worked.

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password_et"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/username" />
```

add inputType = "text" and it works